# What does $n^{O(1)}$ mean?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation, notation

I read an example that said explain what "$f(n)$ is $n^{O(1)}$" means.

I can't interpret the $n^{O(1)}$ syntax. I know what Big $O$ notation is, its just that this example looks odd to me.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_usages

Comment: You are right to be confused; few authors actually define the notation.

Comment: Such notation is commonplace in the literature, and everybody know exactly what it means, despite Raphael's misgivings.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus And yet, every time such a question comes up, people who "know exactly what it means" struggle to explain what that is, exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's short-hand for "$n^{f(n)}$ for some function $f(n)\in O(1)$".  In other words, the function is at most $n^c$ for some constant $c$.

You can see this by directly substituting the definition of $O(1)$ in the expression.  $g(n)=n^{O(1)}$ if there's constant $c$ such that, for all large enough $n$, $f(n)\leq n^{c\cdot 1} = n^c$.

This includes all polynomially-bounded functions.  For example, for $n>0$,
$$n^2+3n = n^2(1+\tfrac3n) = n^{2+\log(1+3/n)/\log n} = n^{O(1)}\,,$$
since, for $n\geq 3$, we have $1<1+\tfrac3n\leq 2$ and $\log n>1$, so the exponent is between $2+\log 2$ and $2$.

Comment: I recall [this thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48527/98) where a disagreement became clear. Just to clarify: you are proposing that $n^{O(1)}$ is the set of all polynomially bounded functions, correct?

Comment: @Raphael, wouldn't it just be the set of all monomial functions with coefficient $1$? e.g. $n^3 + n^2 \notin n^{O(1)}$ and $3n^2 \notin n^{O(1)}$ because they don't follow the form of $n$ to some power $O(1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @ryan: $3n^2 = n^{f(n)}$ where f (n) = 2 + log 3 / log n.

Comment: Aaaaand we once again have proof that such notation is incomprehensible and should be avoided. :'D

Comment: @Raphael Yes, polynomially bounded -- edited to clarify.

Comment: It would be simplier (both for authors and readers) to use $poly(n)$ instead.