# Is this a valid use of big-O notation?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Suppose that $m=O(n^{c+1/2})$ for some real $c>0$ and $x=O(\sqrt{\log m})$. Are the following two computations valid? I understand that I'm abusing notations a bit to get at the desired results.

**Computation 1**
\begin{align}
f(x)\leq \exp(-x^2/2)&=\exp(-O(\log m))\\
&=\exp(-O(\log O(n^{c+1/2})))\\
&=\exp(-O(\log n^{c+1/2}))\\
&\leq \exp(-K_1\log n^{c+1/2})))\\
&=n^{-O(1)}
\end{align}
where $K_1>0$ when $n$ is sufficiently large (i.e. there exists $K_1>0$, $n_0$ such that when $n\geq n_0$, $\exp(-O(\log n^{c+1/2}))\leq  \exp(-K_1\log n^{c+1/2})))$. The last quantity $n^{-O(1)}$ represents the set of polynomially-bounded functions (see [accepted answer in this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79984/what-does-no1-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

**Computation 2**
$$
f(x)\frac{m}{n^{1/2}} \leq n^{-O(1)}\frac{m}{n^{1/2}}=\leq n^{-O(1)}\frac{m}{n^{c+1/2-c}}=O(1)??
$$

Comment: Using big O notation within equations is IMHO, if not terribly sloppy, simply abhorrent mathematics. When you have set $f \in O(g)$, then pick some constant $c$ and write thereafter $f(n) \le c g(n)$ (along with a remark in the lines of "for almost all $n$").

Comment: @dkaeae Sorry but expressions such as "$f(x) = (1+o(1))\sqrt{x}$" or "$f(x)=n\log n + O(n)$" are extremely common and a lot of mathematics would get very tedious if all of those were rewritten as "$f(x) =(1+g(x))\sqrt{x}$ for some function $g\in o(1)$" and so on.

Comment: If $x$ goes to $\infty$, $f(x)$ goes to 0. It is better to talk about $\frac1{f(x)}$

Comment: @David Richerby Yes, I'm aware it is usual practice, but taking those and reformulating them further to something like $\exp(-O(\log(O(n^\dots))))$ just takes things to a whole other level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these computations appear in a paper for me to review, I would like to ask the author to rewrite.

> $$\exp(-x^2/2)\leq \exp\left(-K_1\log n^{c+1/2\,}\right), \text{ where } K_1>0$$

This is wrong. The direction of inequality should be switched. For example, let $n\to\infty$ and $x$ be constant 1, the left hand side remains a constant while the right hand side goes to 0. This error means "Computation 2" is wrong from the start.

> The last quantity $n^{-O(1)}$ represents the set of polynomially-bounded functions.

Instead of $n^{-O(1)}\,$, $n^{O(1)}$ represents asymptotically the set of polynomially-bounded functions.